# Using sec-websocket-protocol for authentication

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

I have a php websocket based application where the websocket is the core. Would it be a good idea to use **sec-websocket-protocol** for **authentication**.

This is my plan.

User logins using there credentials and I use php sessions to track the user between pages.

Now when user initiates the application a random token is generated and stored in Database which is then passed in the header when websocket is initiated. The header looks kind of

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade 
Host:tonywilk.no-ip.org:12352    
Origin:http://********.com:port 
Pragma:no-cache    
Sec-WebSocket-Key:DMF3ByMTLq+cp7AyMN0qUA== 
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol:**Token**      **<-- browser sends token 
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13 
Upgrade:websocket
```

I use the **token** to verify the user and send server respons with handshake

```
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:L6wqtsHk6dzD+kd9NCYT6Wt7OCU=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: **Token**               <-- server replies ok
Upgrade:WebSocket
```

Is this a good idea or is there a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Authorization` header for authentication.

Using `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header for authentication is bad idea, because it changes the header meaning:

> The |Sec-WebSocket-Protocol| header field is used in the WebSocket
> opening handshake.  It is sent from the client to the server and back
> from the server to the client to confirm the subprotocol of the
> connection.  This enables scripts to both select a subprotocol and be
> sure that the server agreed to serve that subprotocol. (c) [RFC 6455 – The WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.3.4)

Comment: It's not possible to send Authorization headers in WebSocket handshakes from browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RatchetPHP for my websocket application.

I can't pass headers when opening a websocket connection, so I pass an OAuth2 token to the websocket uri. It looks like this:

```
new Websocket('ws://localhost:8482?access_token=XXX')
```

If you can easily retrieve query parameters in your websocket application, this is something you could try.

This is the trick I'm using in Sandstone: https://eole-io.github.io/sandstone/authentication.html

Comment: This could be insecure when URLs are logged in the server access logs. Any attacker obtaining the server log would get access to all the user's accounts.